# Change colour of cluster annotation in market. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, markerclusterer

I am trying to change the default colour of the cluster annotation mapkit for iOS, swift.

Is it possible. I can change the individual annotations but not the cluster.

Below is my code.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
        let vehicles = MKClusterAnnotation(memberAnnotations: memberAnnotations)
        vehicles.title = "Photos"
        vehicles.subtitle = nil
        return vehicles
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `markerTintColor`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873822-markertintcolor

e.g.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "marker"
    var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView

    if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
        view = dequeuedView
    } else {
        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.markerTintColor = .blue
    }
    return view
}
```